# How to do split number inside a string ( first position)?

Tags: c#

Follow string:

```
11 blabalba, balbalba balballbal  baba
12 balbal13, afafaf14 1414adad1414 12 12
```

I want it to return something like this (separated by split):

```
array 0: 11
array 1: blabalba, balbalba balballbal  baba
```

Second line:

```
array 0: 12
array 1: balbal13, afafaf14 1414adad1414 12 12
```

How to make a split in the first position?

Comment: Does your string occured in new line? If occured in new line you can split by `\n` probably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var input = "11 blabalba, balbalba balballbal  baba";
var split = input.Split(new [] {' '}, 2);
```

It splits the original string by spaces but returns a maximum of two strings. So it's only going to split using the first space.

[`string.Split` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Your example made it look like you have a string that starts with a number, followed by a space, followed by more text. Whatever the first "word" is - the first text segmented by a space - that's what's going to go in the first array element. Where it came from or whether it's random won't matter. So if the string is "124 ABC 123" you'll get ["124", "ABC 123"].

Comment: What is number 2? `input.Split (new [] {''}, 2);`

Comment: The number two tells it how many elements to split the string into. If I left out the 2 then it would split "124 ABC 123" wherever there is a space, giving you an array of three elements. The 2 tells it to only return 2 elements. It will split the string on the first space, giving you a maximum of two elements, and ignore the rest of the spaces.

Comment: Beautiful to your reply :)

Answer (score 1):

```
            var content = "11  blabalba, balbalba balballbal  baba";

            var splitContent = content.Split(' ');

            splitContent[1] = string.Join(" ", splitContent.Skip(1).Take(splitContent.Length - 1).ToArray());

            splitContent = splitContent.Take(2).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var head = string.Join("", s.TakeWhile(x => char.IsDigit(x)));
var rest = string.Join("", s.Skip(head.Length + 1));

return new [] { head, rest };
```

Or more robustly:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^(?'head'\d+)\s(?'rest'.+)$");

var match = regex.Match(s);

var head = match.Groups["head"].Value;
var rest = match.Groups["rest"].Value;

return new [] { head, rest};
```